# WSL C++ Build for Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), creating build for C++ in Sublime Text 3 is a tedious task.
Here's the way I did it:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "ubuntu run \"g++ `wslpath '${file}'` && ./a.out<inp.in>out.in \" ",
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"$file_name"
}
```

So, thought sharing with all would be nice. Also, any better way is appreciated.